# How I find the total entities from a query, using Google Datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Python script like this to work with Google Cloud DataStore

```
def implicit():
  query = client.query(kind='task')
  query.add_filter('status', '=', True)
  query_iter = query.fetch()
  print(query_iter.num_results)
  for entity in query_iter:
    print(entity['title'])
```

I've inserted 5 'task' entities to DataStore already, and it still print out the titles however, I got the query_iter.num_results is 0, it supposed to be 5 instead. Is there anything wrong with my code.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

num_results will return how many results from the iterator [you have consumed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/api_core/google/api_core/page_iterator.py#L40).  So, to get the total number of results before iterating over the results you need to convert the iterator to a list, i.e. query_results = list(query.fetch()).  Then len(query_results) will have the total number of results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have misunderstood the num_results Is there any proper way to get the total entities instead if using list ?

Comment: You can iterate through all of the results.  So you could move print(query_iter.num_results) to after your for loop to get the correct value of num_results.